# Issue with ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration

Tags: c#, .net, config, .net-assembly, configuration-files

I have this class library that gets loaded into a third-party system.  I've used custom configurations over the years and accessed them via ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration() because that has always allowed me  to associate the configuration file with the dll and avoid having to modify the third-party system config file.  We are currently upgrading systems and now this doesn't work.  The exception gives me the impression it's probing for the assembly by starting in the host exe's location.  My assembly is stored in a separate location to avoid having all my stuff mixed with theirs (easier maintenance since we have a very diverse set of assemblies).  I found that by placing the assembly and its config in the exe's main install directory it does work so I do think binding is the issue of the day here, but like I said I would prefer to avoid copying all my stuff to that directory.  Could this be an issue on how the assembly is loaded into their system?  Was there a change in the codebase for the ConfigurationManager?  What's a more fool-proof way of remotely accessing a config file then?

I've posted a forum question on their site, but thought I'd post something here in case someone is aware of a .NET workaround that doesn't require knowledge of the third-party system API (AutoCAD 2015).  Here's the exception I get which looks to me like some kind of binding issue.  Maybe they have changed how our assemblies are loaded in to the system?  They made several security changes, so I guess that's possible.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException was caught
>     _HResult=-2147024894
>     _message=Could not load file or assembly 'TestAutoCADApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>     HResult=-2147024894
>     IsTransient=false
>     Message=Could not load file or assembly 'TestAutoCADApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>     Source=System.Configuration
>     FileName=TestAutoCADApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>
> FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: DisplayName = TestAutoCADApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>    (Fully-specified)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD 2015/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>
> ## Calling assembly : System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2015\acad.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\co​nfig\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD 2015/TestAutoCADApp.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD 2015/TestAutoCADApp/TestAutoCADApp.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD 2015/TestAutoCADApp.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD 2015/TestAutoCADApp/TestAutoCADApp.EXE.
>
> StackTrace:
>          at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectio​nPermission(IInternalConfigHost host, String typeString, Boolean throwOnError)
>          at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.Creat​eSectionGroupFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
>          at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.Ensur​eSectionGroupFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
>          at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.GetSe​ctionGroup(String configKey)
>          at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSectionGroup​(String sectionGroupName)
>          at TestAutoCADApp.Commands.TestConfigSettingsAccess(A​ction`1 writeAction) in c:\Development-TVA\Visual Studio 2013\TestCode\TestAutoCADApp\TestAutoCADApp\Comman​ds.cs:line 49
>     InnerException:

I can show the custom config code, but if you're not familiar with the system then it doesn't do you any good.  So for now, here's a very super generic example of how I'm accessing it which is the same it's been for a while now.

```
  Uri uriCodeBase = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
  FileInfo appfilePath = new FileInfo(uriCodeBase.LocalPath + ".config");

  ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
  fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = appfilePath.FullName;

  Configuration configuration = null;

  //Retrieve the Configuration file data and return
  configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

  MainGroup mainGroup = configuration.GetSectionGroup("mainGroup") as MainGroup;

  MainSection mainSection = mainGroup.Sections["mainSection"] as MainSection;

  SomeElement someElement = mainSection.SomeElement;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally heard from the vendor and it turns out they used to handle the AssemblyResolve event in their API that happened to resolve issues loading secondary dll's if issues occur when loading the primary dll.  They had evidently had problems with this and decided to take it out with their latest release.  They are suggesting that I handle this by registering the event myself and use the following code (for those who are also interested in this issue).

In the code shown in the original question, add at the beginning:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
```

And the event delegate:

```
    Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Assembly assembly = null;
        Assembly[] assems = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        String name;
        if (args.Name.IndexOf(",") > -1)
            name = args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(","));
        else
            name = args.Name;

        foreach (Assembly assem in assems)
        {
            if (assem.GetName().Name == name)
            {
                return assem;
            }
        }

        return assembly;
    }
```

I wish this made more sense than it does, but I'm guessing that the ConfigurationManager must attempt to access the dll as though it is a secondary dll so that it can read and merge the config file.  It must be probing for the assembly and failing.  But this is just my guess.  I don't know for sure.  Either way, implementing this approach will cause the right assembly to be returned when it does fail.